# A question on an inequality appearing in the proof of Mills' theorem

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I've been reading [Mills' proof](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183510803) that there exists a real number $A$ such that $\lfloor A^{3^n}\rfloor$ is a prime number for all integers $n\ge 1$.

There is a sentence that goes:

> Then by the lemma we can construct an infinite sequence of primes, $P_0,P_1,P_2,\;\cdots$, such that ${P_n}^3<P_{n+1}<(P_n+1)^3-1$.

I understand that from the lemma it obvioulsy follows that for every sufficiently large prime number $P$ there is a prime number $q$ such that $P^3<q<(P+1)^3-1$, but I don't understand why ${P_n}^3<P_{n+1}$.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just start by stating the lemma again :

> For every sufficiently large prime number $P$ there is a prime number $q=f(P)$ such that $P^3<q<(P+1)^3-1$. the prime $q$ depends in the $q$ we have chosen.

Now what the sentence affirms is that we can construct an infinite sequence of primes $p_0,...,p_n$ such that $p_n^3\leq p_{n+1}\leq (p_n+1)^3-1$. This follows directly from the lemma  as you can always apply the lemma for $p_n$ in order to construct $p_{n+1}$ so $p_{n+1}=f(p_n)$, obviously $p_{n+1}$ is not the (n+1)-th prime but it's the prime $q$ which verifies $p_n^3<q<(p_n+1)^3-1$ which always exists according to the lemma.

The complete proof goes is as follow:

- First take $p_0$ a large prime (than $K^3$), using the lemma for $p_0$ there exists $q$ a prime such that $p_0^3\leq q\leq (p_0+1)^3-1 $, let's take $p_1=q$, so we have constructed $p_0,p_1$ such that $p_0^3<p_1<(p_0+1)^3-1$, if you do the same for $p_1$ you will construct $p_2$ and for $p_2$ you construct $p_3$ $etc\cdots$, that's what the second part explains.
- Now Assume that you constructed $p_0,p_1,....,p_n$ ($n\geq 2$)such that for every $0\leq i\leq n-1$ we have $p_i^3\leq p_{i+1}\leq (p_i+1)^3-1$, let $p_{n+1}$ be the prime $q$ such that $p_n^3\leq q\leq (p_n+1)^3-1$ which exists according to the lemma. hence we have constructed $p_0,p_1,....,p_{n+1}$ such that for every $0\leq i\leq n$ we have $p_i^3\leq p_{i+1}\leq (p_i+1)^3-1$

This argument proofs that we can always add another element to the sequence $p_0,...,p_n$ this means that can extend this sequence to an infinite sequence of prime verifying the property.

I hope it's clear now.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, some time after having asked the question I understood what the paper was saying. I was getting confused because I was thinking $P_n$ was the $n$th prime, so I could not see why ${P_n}^3<P_{n+1}<(P_n+1)^3-1$. But actually it's not, because the $n$th prime is denoted by $p_n$ in Mills' paper (with lowercase $p$).

Comment: I finally understood that $P_n$ is the $n$th term of a sequence of primes Mills creates.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I though also, that's why I wrote :"obviously $p_{n+1}$ is not the $(n+1)$-th prime but it's the prime $q$ which verifies $p_n^3<q<(p_n+1)^3−1$  which always exists according to the lemma." which explains the construction

Comment: Thank you again!! Can you help me with [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486502/understanding-the-final-part-of-the-proof-of-mills-theorem)? @Elaqqad